# visual studio 2015 office 2007

Tags: migration, visual-studio-2015, vsto, word-2007, word-addins

my job is to maintain a word-addin, created many years ago, developed by many young programmers like me ;) the addin works fine and there are only a few and easy changes to do from time to time, so my task is to bring the development environment up to date.
The addin was handed over to me as an visual basic project with Visual Studio 2005(in XP-Mode) and a .dot-file
Now I wanted to use Visual Studio 2015, but when I tried to migrate the project there is an error which says the word-version i'm using is not supported by VS2015 and tells me to use Office 2010 minimum. The problem is, my company just uses Office(Word) 2007.
So how can i get VS2015 to migrate the project properly and to use word 2007? Or do I have to use 2010? I read 2010-addins can be used in 2007 and via versa, so this should not be the problem.
Following software is installed:

- Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SP2
- Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SP2
- Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4/4.5/4.5.1/4.5.2/4.6
- Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime
- Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office Second Edition Runtime
- Visual Studio 2015 Community
- Microsoft Office Word 2007

thanks for help :) and please excuse my bad english

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you cannot use Visual Studio 2015 to open the original project, but you can recreate the code in a new project that will still work with Office 2007:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx

Comment: The problem is, I want to make a project for Office 2007 and I can only choose from Office 2010 templates, which I cannot open/create, because I don´t have 2010

Comment: Are you saying you see the Office 2010 templates in Visual Studio 2015? AFAIK you should only see templates for Office 2013 and 2016. Regardless, you can still use the 2010 templates to create add-ins that will run in Office 2007 but you cannot use any Word and Office Object Model features that were introduced in 2010+.

Comment: Yes, i can see 2010 templates. The problem: i need Office 2010 to use a 2010 template, but i wanted to avoid Office 2010 because i want to develope for and with 2007. it seems i dont have a choice :/

Comment: You can still reference the 2007 Interop assemblies in your project, and it will still work with 2010+.